# Java Basic query reg the access specifiers within a file

Tags: java, private, public

I have a file - `LinkedList.java` where I have 3 classes: `LinkedList`, `createLL`, `node`. I am getting error on creating `createLL` and `node` as public class. Why is it so, I mean they are only used by `LinkedList` class but why cannot we declare it as public in same file?

Answer (score 0):

If your classes `createLL` and `node` are used exclusively by `LinkedList`, then what's the point of declaring them `public`? It's better to keep them package-private as it's an implementation detail of your `LinkedList` class.

If you still want to keep them `public` and declare in the same file, you can make them nested classes:

```
public class LinkedList {
    public static class createLL {
        // createLL implementation
    }

    public static class node {
        // node implementation
    }

    // LinkedList implementation
}
```

Comment: ...tx fr reply ..... but still i dont understand how the ide intellij  is throwing error on declaring all classes as public ..... i tried by ...... node class is declared as public and on creating a new class in separate file and making instance of node class in it .... still the node class is shown with error as it is declared public .....sorry for a basic question  but i want to understand